# Convert Google Analytics dimension dateHourMin into date

Tags: r, lubridate

The format returned by Google Analytics of the dimension datehourminute looks like this:

201710060004, so YYYYMMDDHHMM

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehourminute

Before I go parsing the value 201710060004 into pieces to build a date and then mutate the field, is there a built in way using eg lubridate?

Comment: It is not clear about the question `lubridate:ymd_hm(201710060004)#
[1] "2017-10-06 00:04:00 UTC"`

Comment: That actually looks like what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `ymd_hm` on the numeric value

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hm(201710060004)
# [1] "2017-10-06 00:04:00 UTC"
```

Comment: This works for every value I have manually tried.

However, when I try to apply it on a DT I surpisingly get warnings:

        DT_F2[,Time:=ymd_hm('Date Hour and Minute')]
    Warning message:
    All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

It only work for me with this:
        DT_F2[,Time:=ymd_hm(DT_F2[,'Date Hour and Minute']**[[1]]**)]

I hope this is of some help to others. I would however be interested why it doesnt work the "normal" way.

Comment: @Zappageck  Without a reproducible example, it is not clear